# CSS3 property columns not working on firefox v27

Tags: css, firefox

The CSS3 property 'columns' is a shorthand for column-count or column-width. I use the simplest example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bu6df/) on jsfiddle. But it doesn't work. Why?

```
.col {
  border: 1px solid;
  columns:2;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://html5please.com/ only IE10+ and Opera support this without vendor prefixes. This works http://jsfiddle.net/jPmLS/.

```
.col {
  border: 1px solid;
  -webkit-columns:2;
  -moz-columns:2;
  columns:2;
}
```